# Specific word for wordcount program?

Tags: hadoop

My wordcount program is giving me the desired output file which has all the words and their occurrences. Now, I have to append this code to support a query such that, when I enter a specific word, then it outputs the corresponding filenames & the output of the wordcount program should be the input to query.

### I get these errors - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at org.myorg.InvertedIndex.main(InvertedIndex.java:69) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

Comment: as I wanted to ask earlier: how do you want to input that word? As a parameter in the console? I.e. as args[2]? Or some other way?

Comment: @Zenzen yes, the parameter option sounds good! Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to input it as a console parameter while starting the job and both you mapper and reducer are in a single file then you can simply make a static String in this class:

`private static String myWord;`

Then initialize it in the `main()` method:

`myWord = args[2];`

And use it in you `map()` method like this:

```
if(myWord.equals(word.toString()) {
    output.collect(word, one);
}
```

This will only emit pairs  from the mapper to the reducer and the reducer will sum it up. Should work but I did not test it myself.

@Edit: this is mighty strange. The only thing left you can try (imho) is to do something similar to this [WordCount 2.0 example](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Source+Code-N10FD0).

As you can notice (a bit below the source code), they start it like this:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/joe/wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount -Dwordcount.case.sensitive=true /usr/joe/wordcount/input /usr/joe/wordcount/output -skip /user/joe/wordcount/patterns.txt
```

You can change this to:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar InvertedIndex.jar org.myorg.InvertedIndex /user/james/input /user/james/output -word hello
```

And chage the line I suggested (myWord = args[2]) to:

```
for (int i=0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    if ("-word".equals(args[i])) {
        myWord = args[++i];
    }
}
```

Guess you can use that example as it does something similar o what you want to achieve (pass something as a parameter and then use it). You can check where they are storing all the data that comes from the parameters (method configure()) etc.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm close. DO I have to make any changes at the end of main as well? like   FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));  so do i have to specifiy something for args[2] as well?

Comment: no, the lines you mentioned are only for hadoop so he knows from where to take files that need processing and where to store the output. args[2] will be just a simple command line argument passed to the programme (right after args[0] and args[1] ;)) which will be stored in the variable. "myWord=args[2]" is the only line you need to add to the main() method (unless you want to implement some validation in case the user did not provide args[2] of course).

Comment: I get these errors - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at org.myorg.InvertedIndex.main(InvertedIndex.java:69)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
I have modified the program above in my original post, let me know what's wrong

Comment: are you starting the job with the word as your parameter? What is the exact command line command you are using?

Comment: $ javac -Xlint -classpath /home/james/Downloads/hadoop-0.20.203.0/hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar -d  doc InvertedIndex.java  
$ jar -cvf InvertedIndex.jar -C doc/ . 
$ bin/hadoop jar InvertedIndex.jar org.myorg.InvertedIndex /user/james/input /user/james/output hello

Comment: those are the errors i get after running the third command, javac doesn't give out any error.

Comment: @Zenzen - the thing which u suggested previously had less errors, this one is way too complicated with so many errors etc.

Comment: Is there any other way we can do this except command-line parameter passing? Any simpler way?

Comment: @James: unfortunately this is the easiest way (I know of). The only alternative would be to hardcode the word in the class but I don't believe you want that. This is really strange - I run the WordCount 2.0 example on my cpu and it worked just fine. I have no idea why your hadoop doesn't find that last command line argument ;/